# How to use the html files defined inside another war files

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, servlets, jboss

I have 2 War files, say App1 and App2, I have defined my login.html and error.html inside App1, and I am deploying both in the same Jboss Server. Also I am using form authentication, how can I use the login.html and error.html inside the App2 also for authentication  ?

Comment: This is called Single Sign On, or SSO, so google for `single sign on jboss` and you'll find a lot of documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Not exactly SSO, I have already implemented, its something like I have to sing in to one of the APP, not about having login related pages in one war.